# Facebook Api - Authorise giving 400:bad request error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook API for posting message on facebook. I have created a app on developers.facebook.com then I used app_id over there and return url to authorize. but url fails

URL :- https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[API_KEY]&redirect_uri=http://localhost:42485/FaceBookConnect.aspx&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages

This is throwing 400 error. I am using Facebook .net sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to mention redirect url name in "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" at developers.facebook.com under your app setting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The thing that messed stuff up for me was "Native Desktop App" **MUST** be off.